# I really need some help to save my aloe

Tags: diagnosis, plant-health, aloe

(Link to album showing the state it's in in more detail : [imgur link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fkEXV.jpg))

Hello there,

My aloe isn't feeling so well. It stayed in a really small pot for too long and was slowly dying out, so I transplanted it about a week ago, and since then it's almost as if I made everything worse. The leaves are slowly emptying, it seems like it needs more water even if the soil still is a bit moist, and I don't know what to do. Any help would be a godsend, I really love this plant to bits and it pains me to imagine it's not gonna last.

Cheers

[image]

Answer (score 2):

From the plump appearance of the leaves, it looks like it had been over watered in the past. The brown discoloration suggests that the plant had been sitting in direct sun/good amount of light. 
In my experience, aloes need little amount of light only. If you place your plant in a shady spot that receives very little light then it might turn green back. Once it looks green, take it back to a spot that receives indirect light.
Coming to the droopy and soggy leaves, just give it time to heal. Don't give it any water. No water at all. That should give it some time to settle and heal. 
Have you been using fertilizer? Aloes react badly to fertilizers. If you did, stop using it.

Comment: From the album of pictures I agree with @Fariyal. One extra thing I would recommend is to check its roots, if they have rotted you may want to cut off the rotted roots and leave only the healthy ones.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience aloe loves water that is 1-2 inches down, but not on the surface. it will get huge round leaves if you give it plenty of water.